# How to see how many lists an element appears in

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I have a few list of lists:

```
one = [[ham, egg], [sausage, bacon]]
two = [[pancake, bacon], [ham, egg]]
three = [[sausage, bacon], [butter, toast]]
four = [[ham, egg], [butter, toast]]
```

What I'd like to do is be able to iterate over these lists, and find the common occurrences between them. As an idea of where I want to go with this, I'm hoping to have the results come out as such:

```
One
[ham, egg]
matches with Two
[ham, egg]
matches with Four
[ham, egg]
One
[sausage, bacon]
matches with Three
[sausage, bacon]
Three
[butter, toast]
matches with Four
[butter, toast]
```

I'm finding it quite complicated to get to this point. I know you can iterate over a list and compare the list elements to other lists, but that doesn't seem very clean to have to go like:

```
for item in one:
    if item in two or three or four:
for item in two:
    if item in one or three or four:
```

Is there a way I can just compare all the list elements to other lists in one go to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
one = [['ham', 'egg'], ['sausage', 'bacon']]
two = [['pancake', 'bacon'], ['ham', 'egg']]
three = [['sausage', 'bacon'], ['butter', 'toast']]
four = [['ham', 'egg'], ['butter', 'toast']]

lists = [one, two, three, four]
names = {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three', 3: 'four'}

for i in range(len(lists)):
    for j in range(len(lists[i])):
        for k in range(i+1, len(lists)):
            if lists[i][j] in lists[k]:
                print("{} {} matches with {}".format(names[i], lists[i][j], names[k]))
```

The output will be:

```
one ['ham', 'egg'] matches with two
one ['ham', 'egg'] matches with four
one ['sausage', 'bacon'] matches with three
two ['ham', 'egg'] matches with four
three ['butter', 'toast'] matches with four
```

Comment: This produces the exact output I was after, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and maybe clearest way would be to do something like this:

```
mylists = [one, two, three, four]

for i, l in enumerate(mylists):
    for j, other in enumerate(mylists[:i] + mylists[i+1:]):
        for item in l:
            if item in other:
                print(i, j, item)
```

If you really needs the name of the original list in your logs:

```
mylists = {'one': one, 'two': two, 'three': three, 'four': four}

for k1, l1 in mylists.items():
    for k2, l2 in mylists.items():
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        for item in l1:
            if item in l2:
                print(f"item {item} from {k1} found in {k2}")
```

Another way to do such things could be to use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) library:

```
for item1, lst2 in itertools.product(one, [two, three, four]):
    if item1 in lst2:
        print(f"{item1} match")
```

Comment: Awesome, these are all really helpful, thanks for response!